# If Condition not matching 2 Strings in a loop on second Iteration

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to compare values of 2 strings..When i debug it, Its showing me same value of string, but its returning `false` on output.

**Code:**

```
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

        /**** Pick DATE For ROW- ****/
        String currentRowDate= pair.getKey().toString();

        /**** Pick HEADER VALUES to MATCH WITH VALUES- ****/
        String headerColumn= pair.getValue().toString();

        // Splitting HEADER Column
        Object[] headerObj= headerColumn.split(",");

        for(int k=0 ; k< headerObj.length; k++ ){
            String currentHeaderColumn= headerObj[k].toString();

            /********************************************
             * Now Matching Header with Data Values 
             * Loop on [[Header Values- MAP]]
             ********************************************/

            Iterator itr2 = headerRecordsMapList.entrySet().iterator();
            while(itr2.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry pair2= (Map.Entry)itr2.next();

                /***** Pick Records Value and Match with header ******/
                String record= pair2.getValue().toString();
                String matchHeader= pair2.getKey().toString();

                /********************************************
                 * Now checking if Header exits in Records 
                 ******************************************/

                if(currentHeaderColumn.contains("[")){      
                    currentHeaderColumn= currentHeaderColumn.replace("[","");
                }

                if(currentHeaderColumn.equals(matchHeader)){
```

[image]

[image]

On 1st iteration, it matches string successfully..but on 2nd iteration onwards it fails to match string.

Comment: the `hash=0` in the picture (also include code as text in the question not as picture) lets me suspect that they are not equal. Also judging the code in your picture you might want to start intending your code correctly since it gets a lot more easy to read.

Comment: I have added some part of the code..

Comment: @Kirmani88: The hash=0 just shows that in one case the hash hasn't been computed yet. It's done lazily.

Comment: And you don't want to get into the "screenshoting" the debugger thing. Text can be printed to the console; and copied from there. Finally: if equals() returns false, then your values are not equal. Worst case, write a little helper function that does char-by-char comparison and prints the first mismatch.

Comment: @KevinEsche: Not with it showing "25.0" at the bottom, no.

Comment: I have updated my code..Kindly check

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah right, didn´t see that one

Comment: @Kirmani88 you could try calling `String#trim` on both `String`'s before comparing them, maybe you are having a whitespace before or after any of these `String`'s. And the first `25.0` on the picture on the left actually looks like there is one in front